# Pandas series to floats

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
    data = {"col1":["2%", "3%", "4%", "5%"],"col2":["N/A", "N/A", "4%", "5%"]}


    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How I can convert these columns into floats ?

The difficulty I am facing is the strings with the `"N/A"`

I have tried this:

```
for col_name in df.columns:
   df[col_name]=df[col_name].replace(r'%','',regex=True).astype(float)
```

But it fails when i enter into the second column

Can someone help with that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.replace` with a dictionary, then `DataFrame.astype` to convert to float:

```
df = df.replace({'%': '', 'N/A': np.NaN}, regex=True).astype(float)

   col1  col2
0   2.0   NaN
1   3.0   NaN
2   4.0   4.0
3   5.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example this should work. Basically cleans the % symbol and then turns any that does not look like a number into NaN. Then it's trivial to turn into float. This is more resilient if other texts were to appear, but you still need to be able to clean the symbols around text

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for col_name in df.columns:
    aux_series = df[col_name].fillna('').str.replace('%', '')
    aux_series[-aux_series.str.isnumeric()] = None
    aux_series = aux_series.astype(float, errors='ignore')
    df[col_name] = aux_series
```

Comment: Not sure why, In my environment works well. Might be a versions issue?